Error "name 'BoolVariable' is not defined" when using SCons on Godot with C++
I'm trying to use Godot with C++ on Windows and I'm following the GDExtension guide.
When I get to the part where I have to build the C++ bindings and I execute scons platform=windows I see this:
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
NameError: name 'BoolVariable' is not defined:
  File "D:\Programa de archivos (6x8)\Godot\GDExtension\WFC_1\godot-cpp\SConstruct", line 36:
    cpp_tool.options(opts, env)
  File "D:\Programa de archivos (6x8)\Godot\GDExtension\WFC_1\godot-cpp\tools\godotcpp.py", line 325:
    tool.options(opts)
  File "D:\Programa de archivos (6x8)\Godot\GDExtension\WFC_1\godot-cpp\tools\ios.py", line 24:
    opts.Add(BoolVariable("ios_simulator", "Target iOS Simulator", False))

This "BoolVariable" can be found in C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\SCons\Variables, but I don't know what to do now.
I have 2 disk drives, so I tried to follow this guide on both of them.
I've also added C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\SCons to the "Path" variable.
None of that worked.

Try adding the following lines to windows.py, linux.py and ios.py:
from SCons.Variables import BoolVariable


These three had this line:
from SCons.Variables import *.
When I added the line you suggested it worked fine, so I guess the problem was the * import. Thanks for the reply!

While this may have worked, the original code actually should have been fine.   Which version of SCons and python are you using?  And actually my answer above is the recommendedd way by SCons project..

Just in general, files SCons itself brings in (SConstruct, SConscript, or in the Godot case SCsub) are fixed up so they have the SCons API in scope.  Things imported through regular Python import statements aren't able to have that happen automatically, so they have to do that manually. The import in the previous answer works, or you can do a more general from SCons.Script import * to get all of it.  I know "star imports" are often frowned on in the Python world, but that module is specially crafted to make available the SComs API and not other random things, so in this context it's intended to be okay.

I first tried the line that the previous comment suggested and it worked fine. I haven't tested your solution, but I already had the following line before:
from SCons.Variables import *, so maybe the problem was the *. Thanks for the extra useful information about SCons!

it turns out there's an all declaration at the top level of the SCons Variables package that doesn't export the individual variable types. So yes, from SCons.Variables import * won't pick those up. We'll probably end up considering that an error. Use the from SCons.Script import * form to avoid that problem - those are made available at the Script level. Or import individually from SCons.Variables, avoiding the star import there.

To add on to what Mats said, from the SCons manpage

Builder methods that can be called without an explicit environment (indicated in the listing of builders below without a leading env.) may be called from custom Python modules that you import into an SConscript file by adding the following to the Python module:
from SCons.Script import *


